# Recurring Job calls WebApi asynchronously and then modifies the status of the Hangfire job in the callback method

Tags: c#, callback, hangfire

Hangfire 1.6.19
.net core 2.1

Hello,
  When I call a WebApi in the Recurring Job, the job will fail due to the call timeout, so I use the asynchronous method to call, but in this way, all the jobs are executed successfully, and it cannot reflect whether the WebApi call succeeds or fails.

So I judged in the callback method of the asynchronous request. If the WebApi returns an exception, the status of the job is changed as failed.

However, my modification caused Hangfire's failed job list to not work properly. Does Hangfire provide an internal method to modify the job status or do you have any better solutions?

My code is as follows：

```
    [AutomaticRetry(Attempts = 0)]
    [DisplayName("InvokeApi,apiUrl:{0}")]
    public void InvokeApi(string apiUrl, PerformContext context)
    {
        var invocationData = InvocationData.Serialize(context.BackgroundJob.Job);
        int.TryParse(context?.BackgroundJob.Id, out var jobId);

        var client = new RestClient(apiUrl)
        {
            Timeout = -1,
            ReadWriteTimeout = -1
        };
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET)
        {
            Timeout = -1,
            ReadWriteTimeout = -1
        };

        client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
        {
            if (!response.IsSuccessful)
            {
                using (var dbContext = new HangfireContext())
                {
                    using (var transaction = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
                    {
                        var state = dbContext.State.FirstOrDefault(x =>
                            x.JobId == jobId && x.Name == "Succeeded");
                        if (state != null)
                        {
                            state.Name = "Failed";
                            state.Reason = $"StatusDescription={response.StatusDescription},ErrorMessage={response.ErrorMessage ?? "null"}";
                        }

                        var job = dbContext.Job.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == jobId);
                        if (job != null)
                        {
                            job.StateName = "Failed";
                            job.InvocationData = Serialize(invocationData);
                        }

                        var counter =
                            dbContext.AggregatedCounter.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "stats:succeeded");
                        if (counter != null) counter.Value = counter.Value - 1;

                        dbContext.SaveChanges();
                        transaction.Commit();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public string Serialize(InvocationData invocationData)
    {
        var parameterTypes = JobHelper.FromJson<string[]>(invocationData.ParameterTypes);
        var arguments = JobHelper.FromJson<string[]>(invocationData.Arguments);

        return JobHelper.ToJson(new MyJobPayload
        {
            TypeName = invocationData.Type,
            MethodName = invocationData.Method,
            ParameterTypes = parameterTypes != null && parameterTypes.Length > 0 ? parameterTypes : null,
            Arguments = arguments != null && arguments.Length > 0 ? arguments : null
        });
    }


    public class MyJobPayload
    {
        [JsonProperty("type")]
        public string TypeName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("m")]
        public string MethodName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("p", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string[] ParameterTypes { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("a", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string[] Arguments { get; set; }
    }
```

Looking forward to your reply, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It’s finally succeeded, but is there a better way to do it?

```
    [AutomaticRetry(Attempts = 0)]
    [DisplayName("InvokeApi,apiUrl:{0}")]
    public void InvokeApi(string apiUrl, PerformContext context)
    {
        var invocationData = InvocationData.Serialize(context.BackgroundJob.Job);
        int.TryParse(context?.BackgroundJob.Id, out var jobId);

        var dtBegin = DateTimeOffset.Now;
        var client = new RestClient(apiUrl)
        {
            Timeout = -1,
            ReadWriteTimeout = -1
        };
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET)
        {
            Timeout = -1,
            ReadWriteTimeout = -1
        };

        client.ExecuteAsync(request, response => {
            if (!response.IsSuccessful)
            {
                var responseMessage = $"TotalSeconds={DateTimeOffset.Now.Subtract(dtBegin).TotalSeconds},StatusDescription={response.StatusDescription},ErrorMessage={response.ErrorMessage ?? "null"}";

                try
                {
                    var strHangfireDataContext = EngineContext.Instance.ServiceProvider.GetService<ConnectionStringsConfiguration>().HangfireDataContext;
                    var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<HangfireContext>();
                    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(strHangfireDataContext);
                    using (var dbContext = new HangfireContext(optionsBuilder.Options))
                    {
                        using (var transaction = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
                        {
                            var state = dbContext.State.FirstOrDefault(x =>
                                x.JobId == jobId && x.Name == "Succeeded");
                            if (state != null)
                            {
                                var failedState = new FailedState(new Exception(responseMessage));
                                state.Name = failedState.Name;
                                state.Reason = failedState.Reason;
                                state.Data = JobHelper.ToJson(failedState.SerializeData());
                            }

                            var job = dbContext.Job.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == jobId);
                            if (job != null)
                            {
                                job.StateName = "Failed";
                                job.InvocationData = JobHelper.ToJson(new
                                {
                                    Type = invocationData.Type,
                                    Method = invocationData.Method,
                                    ParameterTypes = invocationData.ParameterTypes,
                                    Arguments = invocationData.Arguments
                                });
                            }

                            var counter =
                                dbContext.AggregatedCounter.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "stats:succeeded");
                            if (counter != null) counter.Value = counter.Value - 1;

                            dbContext.SaveChanges();
                            transaction.Commit();
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.LogError("Exception jobId:" + jobId + ";ex:" + ex.ToString());
                }
            }
        });
    }
```